# How to update uploaded file using yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

I want to update the uploaded file using yii2. I have the codes but nothing happens. I don't know whats wrong with my codes. Help me guys.

This is my form

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'doc_for')->textInput(['maxlength'=>true,'style'=>'width:500px']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'doc_from')->textInput(['maxlength'=>true,'style'=>'width:500px']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'drawer_id')->textInput(['maxlength'=>true,'style'=>'width:500px']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'doc_name')->textInput(['maxlength'=>true,'style'=>'width:500px']) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'doc_file')->fileInput() ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-primary' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
</div>
```

Model

```
 public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['reference_no', 'subject', 'doc_date', 'doc_for', 'drawer_id','doc_from','doc_name','doc_file'], 'required'],
        [['reference_no'], 'integer'],
        [['doc_date'], 'safe'],
        [['subject', 'doc_for', 'drawer_id','doc_from','doc_name'], 'string', 'max' => 250],
        [['doc_file'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'extensions' => 'docx, docs, doc',],

    ];
}
```

Controller create

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
$model = new Documents();
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) 
{      
        $project =$model->doc_name;
        $model->upload_file= UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'doc_file');
        $model->upload_file->saveAs('uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension);
        $model->doc_file='uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension;
        $model->save();

        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success','Data saved!');
        return $this->redirect(['view','id'=> $model->reference_no]);
        } 

        else {

        return $this ->render('create', [
            'model'=>$model,
        ]);
        }         

}
```

Controller update

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
     $model = new Documents();
     $model = $this->findModel($id);
     $current_image = $model->doc_file;
     $project =$model->doc_name;
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {         
    $model->upload_file= UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'doc_file');
    if(!empty($upload_file) && $upload_file->size !== 0) {
        //print_R($image);die;
       $model->upload_file->saveAs('uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension);
        $model->doc_file='uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension;
           $model->upload_file = $current_image;
    $model->save();


        Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success','Data updated!');
        return $this->redirect(['view','id'=> $model->reference_no]);
}
} else {
    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
}
```

I don't know whats wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok thanks for the help. I got it. Now its working properly now. This is the code.

actionUpdate Controller:

```
  public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $current_image = $model->upload_file;
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {         
    $project =$model->doc_name;
    $model->upload_file= UploadedFile::getInstance($model,'doc_file');
    if(!empty($model->upload_file) && $model->upload_file->size !== 0) {
        //print_R($image);die;
    $model->upload_file->saveAs('uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension);
    $model->doc_file='uploads/'.$project.'.'.$model->upload_file->extension;
    }
    else
    $model->upload_file = $current_image;
    $model->save();
      Yii::$app->getSession()->setFlash('success','Data updated!');
    return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->reference_no]);
} else {
    return $this->render('update', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $oldmodel = $this->findModel($id);
        $oldimage = $model->image;
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {
            if(isset($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']) && $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] != null)
            {
                if($oldimage && file_exists(Yii::getAlias('@webroot')."/".$oldimage))
                {
                    unlink(Yii::getAlias('@webroot')."/".$oldimage);
                }
                $image = $_FILES['image'];
                $file = $_FILES;

                $new_image['name'] = $_FILES['image']['name'];
                $new_image['type'] = $_FILES['image']['type'];
                $new_image['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
                $new_image['error'] = $_FILES['image']['error'];
                $new_image['size'] = $_FILES['image']['size'];
                $image = $new_image;

                $model->image = Yii::$app->params['imagepath'].time().$file['image']['name'];
                /**
                * for uploding image as it is in folder
                */
                move_uploaded_file($file['image']['tmp_name'],Yii::getAlias('@webroot')."/".$model->image);
            }
            else
                $model->image = $oldmodel->image;

        } else {
            return $this->render('update', [
                'model' => $model,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

It will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks bro. But nothing happens :(.

Comment: What it the error or issue after put the above code?..Can i know?